# Customizing Date cell in the HSTimesSquare TSQCalendarView iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, background, calendar, cells

I am using the https://github.com/HubSpot/HSTimesSquare for implementing a Calendar in my iOS Xamarin app. I want to now highlight certain dates or change background color only of the cells belonging to those dates.

I came across [this](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/timessquare-a-calendar-view-for-ios-and-android-apps-266624ef37b3#.kk7dgajwd) post which says I can customize it, but has no mention on how to do it.

Is there a way I can implement this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: is there any reason you are using that library specifically? It was last updated 3 years ago :/

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift Actually I am using the library which is wrapper for Xamarin which is kinda updated 1.5 years ago. I can not find a Xamarin component which will highlight dates. My only requirement is to highlight multiple dates. If you have any other suggestions on how I can implement them, it would be very helpful